# Does spacetime really exist in quantum gravity?

Tags: quantum-gravity, spacetime

If there are no localized observables in quantum gravity, does spacetime really exist, or might spacetime really be an illusion?

Comment: If there are no observables in quantum gravity, then it means that the theory of quantum gravity is useless. It does not imply that space time does not exist or is an illusion. I vote to close this question because the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @QEntanglement: partially true but I feel like the question could make sense. More or less everyone agrees that the classical notion of space-time should break down at Planck scale and get replaced by some non-commutative version. There is lot to be said on this topic.

Comment: I think the question should be restated to be more specific because "there is a lot to be said on this topic."

Comment: I think questions on "really exist" are border metaphysics, or at least philosophy. I could answer on those lines: "do you really exist or are you a construct of my mind". After all for each of us the only "existence" of the "other" comes through convolutions upon convolutions of electromagnetic pulses that end up in our brain with the illusion "there is something out there" :) . I would also vote to close, unless it changes to "what is the experimental evidence that ...."  , because we start with a framework where existence and reality are not in question.

Comment: He did not say "no observables", he said "no localised observables"

Comment: This question should be reformulated as: how do you reconstruct a space-time from the observables admitted in quantum gravity, namely the S-matrix in flat space, or the AdS boundary theory in asymptotically AdS spaces? This is a topic of very active research.

Comment: @Jim: I agree the question could be reformatted for clarity and will probably recieve more attention if it were ask in this way                             Postulate: If there are no localized observables in quantum gravity, does spacetime really exist, or might spacetime really be an illusion.

Scientifically Relevant Question:

How do you reconstruct a space-time from the observables admitted in quantum gravity, namely the S-matrix in flat space, or the AdS boundary theory in asymptotically AdS spaces

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Strominger thinks [spacetime is an illusion](http://fqxi.org/community/articles/display/176). It's all a Cosmic Hologram at the future boundary of spacetime at the end of time. It projects out the illusion we see around us.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is divided more on the lines of "TOE vs. non-TOE" than "quantum gravity vs. non-quantum gravity". In string theory, the metric tensor is an approximation that arises as an effective description of the graviton field (see also this [post](https://motls.blogspot.com/2013/08/one-cant-background-independently.html) on TRF). But in non-unification theories of quantum gravity, like LQG and its other discrete-spacetime  cronies, spacetime is considered fundamental.